# How to use setAdapter?

Tags: java, android

I have a doubt related with setAdapter. Somebody could detail or explain the functions and how to understand a code like this.

```
mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.drawer_list_item, mServices));
```

detail for example: 
new ArrayAdapter ; this.

Comment: You say you have a doubt and then don't tell us what it is.  Questions like this should be google searched...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list adapter is an object that adapts a collection objects for display in a `ListView`. `ArrayAdapter` is one simple implementation that maps an array of objects.

```
mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.drawer_list_item, mServices));
```

This line is mapping an array of strings (`mServices`) for display in a `ListView` (`mDrawerList`). The second argument to the adapter's constructor is the layout that will be used to render each list item.

List adapters, and adapters in general are a long and complex topic that isn't going to be explained in an SO answer. Try these links,

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html